# IIS Pass-Through Authentication failing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8.5

I'm trying to run my MVC App on a company server, witch only company users (a lot) are going to access. I'm new at this. It should happen using Pass-through Windows Authentication (Current Acc on remote desktop connection is valid). The MVC connects to a database, which is located on the server. I've read tons of forum questions and replies about this issue, but I couldn't quite find a solution to my problem. ConnectionString:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CaseDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestGeorgi" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Just to be clear, I want every user to be able to connect with the site (and db) with its own Windows acc, and he must validate with his name, not through 'Domain/Servername$'. This also means that I cannot hardcode a single acc name and pass in the connection string (I think).

My acc, as well as SYSTEM, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE, Administrators, IIS_IUSRS,  all have full control permissions for the site's folder (for now).

NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$ and my acc have access to the database.

As you see, I've tried many options to get through to my site (which BTW works on my own computer with connection to the external DB - ConnectionString has different Data Source ofc). Almost all of these efforts ended up in this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'Domain\Servername$'.
```

I don't want to access it through the server, and even if I did, it should've worked, because it has rights to access the DB.

Please be kind enough to help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that you need to enable .Net Authentication. Be ready to enable it on every publish, cause this thing has its own temper...